PSQL Not Showing Results
I am connecting to psql using pgadmin. I have not connected to psql before and was just testing.
Why does this query return 0 results?

Shouldn't I see the bottom picture in the results? What am I doing wrong? It looks like my connection is correct, so I don't believe that is the issue.

Edit #1:
Here is another example:


Because you did not read the docs psql Entering SQL Commands: Ordinarily, input lines are sent to the server when a command-terminating semicolon is reached..

Edited my post to have more examples.

The problem is that you don't use the ; after each SQL statement. It's the ; that tells psql to send the statement to the server. If you have constructed an invalid SQL statement, you get an error. All behavior that you have shown here, is as expected.

The answer is the same read the docs, see Prompting section.

To add to the above comments, if you enter a statement without the terminating semi-colon (;), then the statement remains in the buffer, so if you type another statement and press enter again the statements will be concatenated.

In other words try the second line again.

Thanks FrankHeikens, snakecharmerb, and Jasen. It works now, I appreciate your helpful responses!

The ; character is what sends it to the server.
Example of what would work:

Select 'test' as test_column;

